# Dynamic compilation still does not work in ASP.NET 5 RC1?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dynamic-compilation, edit-and-continue

The scenario from the "Dynamic Development" section from here
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5

does not work in ASP.NET RC1. I start a new MVC6 project, run it with the debugger, change some string, save the changes, nothing happens. It does work, however, if I start the project without debugging. Also, it works in console applications, for example, with and without debugging.

I know it was an issue in previous version of ASP.NET 5. Is it still not fixed or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you launch project from visual studio or from console ?

Comment: From Visual Studio. If run from console, it will run without the debugger, and therefore will work fine, I suppose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET vNext - compile code dynamically not working for me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082161/asp-net-vnext-compile-code-dynamically-not-working-for-me)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic compilation doesn't work with the debugger attached. You must run without debugger.

Here's my previous answer a little more details:
[ASP.NET vNext - compile code dynamically not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24082161/asp-net-vnext-compile-code-dynamically-not-working-for-me/24087044#24087044)

Comment: So nothing has changed since the last year.

Comment: Then it's useless feature!